# Replacing NA's with asterisks (*)

Tags: r, replace

I have a data set which I read from my a .csv file. After some editing work, I now need to write it as a .txt file with (i) all quotes removed (ii) every `NA` in the whole file to be replaced by an asterisk, `*`, and (iii) first row (variable names) excluded.

The following scripts, so far, remove quotes and am just wondering how can (ii) and (iii) can be added or may be done.

```
write.table(ped5, "ped5.txt" ,row.names=FALSE)
ped5 <- read.table("ped5.txt", header=TRUE)
write.table(ped5, "ped7.txt", row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For  (ii) use `na = "*"` and for (iii) `col.names=FALSE`.
So:

```
write.table(ped5,"ped7.txt",row.names=FALSE,quote=FALSE, na="*", col.names=FALSE)
```

It's all to find on [help page to `write.table`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/write.table) (`?write.table`).